# how to overlay image on another image in compose android

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

i want overlay images on android compose
like this image:

[image]

now i am using box with row :

```
        Row() {
        Box(
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Row(modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 30.dp)) {
                Box(
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                ) {
                    AvatarType(2, modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 15.dp))
                }
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 0.dp),
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                ) {
                    AvatarType(1, modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 0.dp))
                    AvatarType(1, modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 25.dp))
                    AvatarType(1, modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 45.dp))

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

but i can't controll items in other states

how can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is to use Modifier.offset on each element relative to last index and current index.

I create a Composable to draw image with CircleShape and white border

```
@Composable
private fun CircleImage(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    painter: Painter
) {

    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .clip(CircleShape)
            .size(100.dp)
            .background(Color.White)
            .padding(10.dp)
    ) {
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier
                .clip(CircleShape),
            painter = painter,
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds,
            contentDescription = null
        )
    }

}
```

For a resource list such as

[image]

It results

[image]

With Code

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun Test() {
    val resourceList = remember {
        listOf(
            R.drawable.avatar_1_raster,
            R.drawable.avatar_2_raster,
            R.drawable.avatar_3_raster,
            R.drawable.avatar_4_raster,
            R.drawable.avatar_5_raster,
        )
    }

    Column(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(backgroundColor)) {
        Box {
            resourceList.forEachIndexed { index, res ->
                CircleImage(
                    modifier = Modifier.offset {
                        IntOffset(x = (resourceList.lastIndex - index) * 20.dp.roundToPx(), 0)
                    },
                    painter = painterResource(id = res)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://medium.com/proandroiddev/custom-layouts-with-jetpack-compose-bc1bdf10f5fd with custom layouts just in case some one is interested!